# Как дождаться завершения привязки к DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю браузер на основе CefSharp [по примеру из исходников](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example).

Есть VM, которая олицетворяет собой вкладку браузера. В ней идет привязка к свойству `WebBrowser`, через которое можно выполнять уже различные манипуляции браузером: делать переход по ссылкам, выполнять JS-код на странице и т.д.

В`MainVm`лежит коллекция вкладок и метод, создающий новые вкладки.

---

Проблема в следующем.

Если вызывать метод `CreateAndLoadTab` в `MainVm`, то он выкинет исключение `NullReferenceException` на строке `tab.Load();`.

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит потому, что сам компонент браузера после создания вкладки не успевает загрузиться и к моменту вызова метода привязка к свойству `WebBrowser` еще не произошла.

Как правильно дождаться привязки свойства зависимости?

**BrowserTabViewModel:**

```
public class BrowserTabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IWpfWebBrowser webBrowser;
    public IWpfWebBrowser WebBrowser
    {
        get { return webBrowser; }
        set { Set(ref webBrowser, value); }
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        WebBrowser.Load("https://site.com");
    }
}
```

**MainVm:**

```
public class MainVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<BrowserTabViewModel> Tabs {get;} = new ObservableCollection<BrowserTabViewModel>();

    public void CreateAndLoadTab()
    {
        var tab = new BrowserTabViewModel();
        Tabs.Add(tab);
        tab.Load(); //Тут будет NullReferenceException
    }   
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:BrowserTabViewModel}">
        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" />
```

Comment: Ну, про временные гарантии лучше спрашивать у разработчиков. Код `var tab = new BrowserTabViewModel(); tab.Load();` на мой взгляд выглядит нормально.

Comment: `<cef:ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />` - хм, а это точно должно создавать новый экземпляр `IWpfWebBrowser`?

Comment: @Андрей, Новый экземпляр создается при создании новой вкладки `TabControl`. Т.е. при добавлении элемента в коллекцию `Tabs`.

Comment: Где это место в коде?

Comment: @Андрей, `Tabs.Add(tab);` и `ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"`

Comment: Экземпляр WebBrowser здесь не создается. Приведите код где он создается. Его у вас нет?

Comment: @Андрей, Тогда я не до конца понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Экземпляр создается где-то в недрах CefSharp. Но он точно создается новый, т.к. если не вызывать никаких методов, то браузером можно пользоваться нормально. Все вкладки прогружаются и свойства привязываются.